react & jest mocked zustand module max callstack issue
I'm using this zustand mocked module code from their docs: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/testing.md#jest
It works successfully for when I jest.mock('zustand', '../mocks/zustand.ts) in a spec file that tests a simple zustand store in isolation (I see the console logs from the mock file).
However, jest errors out with max callstack exceeded when I try to use the mocked zustand module with a simple counter component as a simple test and I'm not sure why:
counter-store.ts
import { create } from 'zustand';

export interface CounterState {
  count: number;
  increment: () => void;
  decrement: () => void;
}

export const useCounterStore = create<CounterState>((set) => ({
  count: 0,
  increment: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 })),
  decrement: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
}));

counter.tsx
import { useCounterStore } from 'shared/stores';

export const Counter = () => {
  const count = useCounterStore((state) => state.count);

  return (
    <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
  );

counter.spec.tsx
jest.mock('zustand', () => {
  return jest.requireActual('../mocks/zustand');
});

import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import { Counter, type CounterState, useCounterStore } from 'shared';

describe('Counter Component', () => {
  let store: CounterState;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = useCounterStore();
  });

  it('should render with pre-set count state', () => {
    act(() => {
      store.increment();
    });

    render(<Counter />);

    expect(screen.getByText('Count: 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

Other test files that use the mocked zustand module to test zustand stores in isolation work, but the counter spec fails with this error:
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      21 |     // Suppresses console.error output from ReactDOMTestUtils.act deprecation warning due to third party library
      22 |     if (typeof args[0] === 'string' && !args[0].includes('ReactDOMTestUtils.act')) {
    > 23 |       console.error(...args);
         |               ^
      24 |     }
      25 |   });
      26 | });

